# Find the equation of a line parallel to the y-axis, that goes through the point $(\pi,0)$

Tags: infinity

I have been trying to do this problem and I am very confused.

I know the gradient is infinity when any line is parallel to the y-axis, therefore, $y = \infty \cdot x + c$, right ($y = mx + c$ being the general equation a straight line)?

We know $y = 0$, therefore $0 = \infty \cdot \pi + c$ and so $c = -\infty \cdot \pi$. Therefore, $y = \infty \cdot x - \infty \cdot \pi$. And therefore $y = 0$ which would seem to check-out?

But, the answer I have been given (by my teacher) says $x = \pi$. Please can somebody explain how you come to this answer?

Answer (score 2):

Is this in $\mathbb{R}^2$? If so, the equation $y=mx+b$ will not help you, as the slope of any line parallel to the $y$-axis is undefined. Instead, a vertical line (parallel to $y$-axis) has the equation $x=a$, where $a$ is the $x$-intercept of the line. This should clarify the (correct) answer provided by your teacher.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your quick response. Would you care to explain the derivation of x = a?

Comment: Draw an arbitrary vertical line. What do all of the points on it have in common? What does it mean to be a point on the vertical line?

Answer (score 0):

First time answering, hope my help is good!

Firstly, you haven't really covered all the continuous points that satisfy our line as you have only shown that $(\pi,0)$ lies on it through substitution.

Secondly, try to avoid putting $\infty$ inside a real function ($\Bbb R^2$). This is because $\infty$ is defined to be larger than any real number, making it a concept that is undefined. Hence it is not a real number.

This is why we say that the gradient of a line parallel to the y-axis is undefined.

Additionally, from what we know:
\begin{aligned}
m = gradient &= \frac{rise}{run}
\end{aligned}
If we wanted to define the gradient of a line parallel to the y-axis, which is $\infty$:

"rise" can be whatever real number you wanna put in there **except** 0, and "run" is 0 because the line doesn't deviate along the x-axis.

This means that we can end up with representations such as:
\begin{aligned}
m=gradient=\frac{1}{0}=\frac{2}{0}=\frac{7}{0}=\frac{1982749816487134}{0}
\end{aligned}
i.e:
\begin{aligned}
m=gradient=1=2=7=1982749816487134
\end{aligned}
Which are all mathematically absurd. Hence, our line with infinite gradient is **undefined** because **it cannot be concretely defined** (for now!).

So coming back to your question from what we have just thought about, it doesn't seem to be appropriate to define a vertical line in the form $y=mx+c$ where $m=\infty$ as $\infty$ does not make our function **real**. Even though we know very well that it is the general formula for most cases of straight lines.

Instead, we have a **special case** of a straight line where the gradient $m$ is undefined, where the formula for a straight line is no longer appropriate.

Here, we should focus on what is common with all the points that lie on a line parallel to the y-axis. For instance, with the problem that your teacher gave you: "define the equation of a line parallel to the y-axis passing through $(\pi,0)$" It could help to draw this out.

[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KHdW.png)

Here we can see that on our straight line passing through $(\pi,0)$, there are other points $(\pi,2),(\pi,3),(\pi,4),(\pi,5),$ and even $(\pi,-1)$.

We now have to define the equation of a line that holds true for all **continuous** points on that line, and yes, it can be *independent* to either the $x$ coordinates or the $y$ components. (But not both!!)

So if we proposed that the line containing all the points was $x=\pi$, we can show that it holds true by subbing in the $x$ component of each point:

- Subbing in $(\pi,0)$ into $x=\pi$ gives $\pi=\pi$ which is true.
- Subbing in $(\pi,-1)$ into $x=\pi$ gives $\pi=\pi$ which is true.
- Subbing in $(\pi,2)$ into $x=\pi$ gives $\pi=\pi$ which is true.

.

.

.

and so on.

This is why the answer that your teacher gave you is $x=\pi$.

Notice how we didn't even have to use the $y$ component of each coordinate!

Answer (score 0):

$x=\pi$.  That is the line through $(\pi,0)$ and parallel to the $y$-axis.

$x$ is fixed at $\pi$;  whereas there are no restrictions on $y$.